# Kendo UI Mobile - Refreshing page on local view displays blank white screen

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Let's say I have a website at example.com

It contains two local views, "Database" and "Year"

Initially, the Database view is loaded.

The user navigates to the "Year" view.

The address bar (at least in android 2.3) now reads example.com#Year

The user then decides to refresh the page for whatever reason.

The address example.com#Year is refreshed and the user is greeted with a blank white screen.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this situation? Obviously, whichever view the user is at, if refreshed, I would like for it to display..

Thanks!

**Update:**

Here is some code to help with describing my problem:

html:

```
<div data-role="view" id="Database">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><strong>This is the Database view</strong></p>
        <a data-role="button" id="databaseButton" href="#Year">Go to Year View</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="view" id="Year">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><strong>This is the Year view</strong></p>
        <a data-role="button" id="yearButton">Refresh Page</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

script:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document).body, {
    initial: "Database"
});

$("#yearButton").click(function() {
    // location.reaload();
    // cannot simulate page refresh by the user in jsfiddle

    // the current browser address is example.com/index.html#Year
    // reloading this address produces a blank white screen
    // because of the #Year parameter
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VUN3g/16/

Comment: Could you please replicate this is jsfiddle or jsbin so we can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that you are using the latest release of Kendo UI (2012.3.1114) and jQuery 1.8.2?

I was unable to replicate the issue with your code and testing on Android 2.3 with the following URL...

http://jsbin.com/aqireb/1

Comment: Thanks Burke, it has been solved. I did have the latest release of Kendo and JQuery. I had put a flash of unstyled content fix in the data-init function of my initial view, which obviously wouldn't trigger if that view was never loaded. I have since bound it my window's load event, and all is working. I'm marking this as solved because it lead me to retracing my view functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice! The FOUJUI is nasty stuff for sure.